# How can I obtain mutants files (.class or .java) on disks? Is there a suitable mutation testing tools to recommend?

Tags: java

I am now conducting mutation testing on java programs and only need to conduct research on mutants files. How can I only obtain mutants files on disk?

I have tried Mujava and PIT.

However, Mujava may report exceptions often when it comes to some complex annotations and structures, and PIT seems to only report the final mutation kill/fail report and don't enable users to find specific internal mutants it generated.

Is there any tool that can be more useful and enable me to get mutants generated as .class or .java files?

Answer (score 0):

If you can code then there is a raw way in which you can get mutated / changed files list using Watch Service feature of JAVA 7.

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

Then register this WatchService for a given directory like the following:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("Path/To/Watched/Directory");
dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

Example - How to use.

```
while (true) {
    WatchKey key;
    try {
        // wait for a key to be available
        key = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return;
    }

    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        // get event type
        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

        // get file name
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
        Path fileName = ev.context();

        System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);

        if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
            continue;
        } else if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {

            // process create event

        } else if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {

            // process delete event

        } else if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {

            // process modify event

        }
    }

    // IMPORTANT: The key must be reset after processed
    boolean valid = key.reset();
    if (!valid) {
        break;
    }
```